# How to use ORDER BY on DISTINCT TO_CHAR(dateField 'DD/MM/YYYY')?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to sort my query results

My Query is

```
SQL> SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(processed_dt ,'DD/MMM/YYYY'), 
     process_name, process_event_code 
     FROM process_hist_view 
     WHERE process_id ='XXX' 
     group by processed_dt, process_name, process_event_code;
```

for an example

```
Actual data
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Processed_dt        |  Process_name       | Process_event_code
---------------------------------------------------------------------
10-Jan-2014         |ABC                  |140
12-Jan-2014         |BCD                  |240
10-Jan-2014         |BCD                  |240
15-Feb-2013         |ABC                  |140
10-Jan-2014         |ABC                  |140
10-Jan-2014         |BCD                  |240
....
....
```

I used `DISTINCT TO_CHAR()` to avoid duplicates

```
Result
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Processed_dt      |  Process_name       | Process_event_code
---------------------------------------------------------------------
10-Jan-2014       |ABC                  |140
12-Jan-2014       |BCD                  |240
10-Jan-2014       |BCD                  |240
15-Feb-2013       |ABC                  |140
....
```

Now I need to order by `processed_dt`.

I tried

```
SQL> SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(processed_dt ,'DD/MMM/YYYY'),
     process_name, process_event_code 
     FROM process_hist_view 
     WHERE process_id ='XXX' 
     GROUP BY processed_dt, process_name, process_event_code 
     ORDER BY processed_dt; 

SQL> SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(processed_dt ,'DD/MMM/YYYY'), 
     process_name, process_event_code 
     FROM process_hist_view 
     WHERE process_id ='XXX' 
     GROUP BY processed_dt, process_name, process_event_code 
     ORDER BY 1; 

SQL> SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(processed_dt ,'DD/MMM/YYYY'),
     process_name, process_event_code 
     FROM process_hist_view 
     WHERE process_id ='XXX' 
     GROUP BY processed_dt, process_name, process_event_code 
     ORDER BY DISTINCT TO_CHAR(processed_dt ,'DD/MMM/YYYY');


SQL> SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(processed_dt ,'DD/MMM/YYYY') AS abcxyz, 
     process_name, process_event_code 
     FROM process_hist_view 
     WHERE process_id ='XXX' 
     GROUP BY processed_dt, process_name, process_event_code  
     ORDER BY abcxyz;
```

`ORDER BY 1` I am not sure is it correct or wrong. I found this in google.

I am using this query in stored proc and Need to some calculations.

All the query's are not working. I am using Oracle DB.

Thanks for your help time on this.

CVSR Sarma

Comment: "not working" only gives us a tiny amount of information. Did the queries result in an error? Or just no ordering? Or some ordering which wasn't right?

Comment: Nope, query is returning the results, its unordered results.

Comment: What results? Is there any obvious ordering at all? Note that you've given 4 different queries - are they all giving the exact same results? (I'd have expected the first one to work.)

Comment: yes @JonSkeet all 4 query's are returning same results.
If I removed order by there is no change in results.

Comment: is your `processed_dt` column of type `DATE`??

Comment: yes its a date field.

Comment: How come you are getting `DD-MON-YYYY` formatted date  while using `TO_CHAR(processed_dt ,'DD/MM/YYYY')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ORDER BY is behaving exactly as expected - you're ordering by a string containing a date in the format `DD/MM/YYYY`, which Oracle happily will happily sort as

```
10/02/2014
11/01/2014
15/01/2014
...
```

To get the correct behaviour, you'll have to sort by the date itself:

```
SELECT formatted_date, process_name, process_event_code 
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT 
    trunc(processed_dt), -- this is our sorting column
    TO_CHAR(processed_dt ,'DD/MM/YYYY') as formatted_date, 
    process_name, process_event_code 
  FROM process_hist_view 
  WHERE process_id ='XXX' 
  ORDER BY trunc(processed_dt)
)
```

BTW: I removed the GROUP BY, because GROUP BY in combination with DISTINCT doesn't make any sense.

Comment: for trunc function we need to give format? or its not required?

Comment: @sarma: if you provide no format, TRUNC truncates the time portion from the date.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong about sql code, Correct code is 1843